# Use formula to sum cells which is reference of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Use formula to sum cells which is reference of another cell

My requirement:

Note: Inside bracket is the formula that particular cell holds

A1(=Sheet1!A1) ==> 6

A2(=Sheet1A2) ==> 2

A3(=Sheet1!A3) ==> 2

A4 (=SUM(A1:A3)) ==> 0 (is what I am getting) but I need A4=10

Help me out with this.

Comment: make sure that your numbers are true numbers and not numbers stored as text.

Comment: Formulas seems okay.

Comment: @Harun24HR but am not getting the right answer if my formula is okay

Comment: @BruceWayne the data looks like 6 2 2

Comment: The only reason for you to get `0` is that your numbers are stored as text.  SUM ignores text.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think you didn't understand my question, It is that my cells are reference of some cell so it is in general only then why it is not displaying right answer?

Comment: If the formula isn't working as @Scott says - does `A1` contain the text `=Sheet1!A1` or the formula?  Are the numbers returned naturally aligned left or right (i.e. when no alignment forced on the cell)?  Right means it's a number, left means it's text.

Comment: I understand your question, I think you are dismissing my answer without further research into the problem.  There is nothing wrong with the formula.  If the numbers are true numbers then it should work.  The issue is with the data.  Fix the data and the problem will end.

Comment: The formulae work fine for me, must be a text vs. number issue as everyone's been mentioning. Try reproducing this circumstance. Don't copy paste the data, since that would cause you to run into the same issue. Manually Enter values into cells in `Sheet1` and then manually enter the formulae and see if you still get `0`. Because when I did this I got `10`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Scott, one of your cells probably contains a number stored as text.
To check try either selecting all the cells and setting the format or troubleshoot which cell(s) is(are) causing the problem.

```
=SUM(VALUE(A1),VALUE(A2),VALUE(A3))
```

This will convert each cell to a numeric value. If that works then start swapping out the value function for just the cell reference (e.g. -`Value(A1)` becomes simply `A1`) and see which cell breaks the sum function. Once you find that cell you can wrap whatever formula is in that cell in the value function to force it to store the numeric value.